# Meltano tap-mysql throwing `No RECORD message received` error

Tags: amazon-ec2, etl, meltano

I'm building an ETL pipeline using Meltano that extracts data from a db using `tap-mysql` extractor and dumps the data into an S3 bucket in AWS.

Here's what I'm doing - testing locally with this `meltano.yml` file:

```
version: 1
default_environment: dev
project_id: 31c666cb-33b9-43a3-884f-88af7ea504e4
environments:
- name: dev
  config:
    plugins:
      extractors:
      - name: tap-mysql
        config:
          host: remoteHost
          port: 3306
          user: admin
          database: realDb
          password: my-secret-pw
      loaders:
      - name: target-s3-csv
        config:
          aws_access_key_id: accessKeyId
          aws_secret_access_key: accessKey
          s3_bucket: dest_bucket
- name: staging
- name: prod
plugins:
  extractors:
  - name: tap-mysql
    variant: transferwise
    pip_url: pipelinewise-tap-mysql
    select:
    - realDb-srcTable.*'
    metadata:
      realDb-srcTable:
        replication-method: INCREMENTAL
        replication-key: id
  loaders:
  - name: target-jsonl
    variant: andyh1203
    pip_url: target-jsonl
  - name: target-s3-csv
    variant: transferwise
    pip_url: git+https://github.com/transferwise/pipelinewise-target-s3-csv.git
```

When I run the config test command `meltano --environment=dev config tap-mysql test` locally (local meltano project/mysql server) it shows this response:

```
2023-06-30T17:41:58.329056Z [info] Environment 'dev' is active
Plugin configuration is valid
```

It's running perfectly against the **local database server** that I ran just for testing purposes .. but the issue is that when I run it in an EC2 instance targeting the real database (running on the same aws env - same vpc) but its throwing this error when I run the same command to test the config it returns this response:

```
2023-07-01T18:13:24.540423Z [info     ] Environment 'dev' is active
Need help fixing this problem? Visit http://melta.no/ for troubleshooting steps, or to
join our friendly Slack community.

Plugin configuration is invalid
No RECORD message received
```

I tried the following:

- Creating an EC2 Connection from RDS for the database I'm targeting specifying the EC2 instance where I have the meltano project trying to connect to the Db.
- I also ran this command to list the tables and it returned the one that I want to read `meltano --environment=dev select --list --all tap-mysql` and it returned it locally / remotely.

Comment: Something on your "production" setup isn't right. I'd hop on the production server and run `meltano --environment=prod invoke --dump=config tap-mysql` does the data look right? Are you using the prod environment? etc you need to figure out what's going on with the connection. Also fwiw I think running invoke will give you better information on why something is failing than the test command. The test command just tells you "somethings wrong!"